# Bitbake hello world example fails

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm following this tutorial:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-hello.html

My bitbake version is 1.50.0 and BBPATH is following:

```
export BBPATH="/home/testusr/projects/bitbake_example/bitbake_sample_project/hello"
```

and I'm at the last step of the tutorial with following file structure:

```
/home/testusr/projects/bitbake_example/bitbake_sample_project $ tree
.
├── hello
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── base.bbclass
│   └── conf
│       ├── bblayers.conf
│       └── bitbake.conf
└── mylayer
    ├── conf
    │   └── layer.conf
    └── printhello.bb
```

The problem is when I try to build that:

```
/home/testusr/projects/bitbake_example/bitbake_sample_project/hello $ bitbake printhello
WARNING: Layer mylayer should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_mylayer in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
Loading cache: 100% |                                                                                                       | ETA:  --:--:--
Loaded 0 entries from dependency cache.
WARNING: No bb files in default matched BBFILE_PATTERN_mylayer '^\/home\/testusr\/projects\/bitbake_example\/bitbake_sample_project\/mylayer/'
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'printhello'
```

The warning is saying that there are **no bb files under**:
/home/testusr/projects/bitbake_example/bitbake_sample_project/mylayer/

but this file is clearly there as can be seen in tree output, so I'm totally confused.

Comment: What's the **exact** content of `BBFILES` variable in conf/layer.conf?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, since there was mistake in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the tutorial in layer.conf file. It had:

```
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/\*.bb"
```

Instead of:

```
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/*.bb"
```

and that's why it couldn't be found.

Comment: Hi LLL, please send a patch, this probably sneaked in while bitbake documentation migrated to sphinx.

Comment: @qschulz sure, I've just reported that